# Operation applied on values of a type

Tags: go

As mentioned in Go specification:

"A type determines a **set** of values together with operations and methods specific to those values."

---

To introduce an operation or method to be applied on the values of a  *type*,

Is that operation applied on values (taken from a set) supposed to give the result (or value) from the same set?

For example, in the below code, `findName()` is not supposed to be a method on type `user`. Instead `findName()` should be a helper function.

```
type user struct {
    name  string
    email string
    age   int
}

func (u user) findElder(other user) user {
    if u.age >= other.age {
        return u
    }

    return other
}

func (u user) findName() string {
    return u.name
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"operations and methods **specific** to those values" does not mean that they are **unique** to those values, or that they **result** in those values.

According to Google, "specific" means "clearly defined or identified." In this quote from the Go spec, the word "specific" is used with regard to the fact that Go is strongly typed, meaning that operations and methods work on the types that they are defined or identified to work on.

For example, the `==` operator is *specified* to work on integer types, thus, the `==` operator is *specific* to values of `int`, `int32`, `uint8`, etc.

Comment: My understanding for "operations and methods specific to those values"..... `findName()` should be a helper function(`func findName(u user) string { return u.name }`) but not a method(`func (u user) findName() string { return u.name }`). So, `findName()` is not an operation specific to those values of type `user`

Comment: @overexchange It seems you have your own definition of "specific" which doesn't align with what the Go authors meant in that quote. If you want to understand what they meant, I hope my explanation will help you.

Comment: `%`, `+`,  `*` operators are specific to `int`, because the operation on those values result in the value(that is part of same set).

I think, Go authors doesn't mean, `%` operator is not specific to `float64`, just because `%` cannot be applied on floats

Comment: Again, you are making up your own definition that clearly doesn't match what the authors intended. Why keep repeating it?

Comment: Spec says, "specific to those values" but not "specific to type `int`, `int32`, `uint8`, etc." (as you mentioned in the answer). "specific to those values"  mean specific to set of values of a particular type

Comment: @HymnsForDisco The OP has a rather large track record of "creating problems out of thing air". Language barrier might explain _some_ _parts_ of these misunderstandings.

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think that the operation applied on values (taken from a set) are supposed to give the result (or value), only from the same set. They can be from a different set of values as well. It all depends on the use case, the design of the type and the operation.

So in your case, `findName()` can very well be a method even though it is returning something not in the set of input values.